# Replacing patterns with grep and regex

Tags: regex, vim, grep

I was wondering if with *grep* and regex we can do something in the spirit of the following example:

**Original text**:

```
name_1_extratext
name_2_extratext
```

**Target**:

```
name_extratext_1
name_extratext_2
```

I am particularly interested in doing this within *Vim*. Thanks

Comment: `grep` doesn't "do" anything to what t matches; it only *matches*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bohemian's comment about `grep` only doing matching also applies within Vim. "grep" and "regex" are not, or should not, be vague buzzwords you throw at a problem. They are tools that may or may not be adapted to the class of problem you are having and a large part of learning is acquiring the correct intuition for what tool to use in what case.

In Vim, what you want to do is a *substitution*. It doesn't involve `grep` at all but it definitely involves regular expressions.

In this specific case, you would do something like this:

```
:%s/\(.*\)\(_\d\+\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2
```

or this variant of @bohemian's answer:

```
:%s/_\([^_]\+\)_\(.*\)/_\2_\1/
```

or anything that works and makes sense to you, really. Ideally not something you copy/pasted from the internet but something you really understand.

Reference:

- The `:s` command is introduced in chapter 10 of the user manual: `:help 10.2`, and further documented under `:help :s`.
- The `%` range is also introduced chapter 10 of the user manual: `:help 10.3`, and further documented under `:help :range`.
- Vim's own regular expression dialect is extensively documented under `:help pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` doesn't "do" anything to what it matches; it only matches.

Use `sed`:

```
echo "name_1_extratext" | sed -E 's/_([^_]+)_(.*)/_\2_\1/'
```